# How can I set PIN for a X509Certificate2 programmatically?

Tags: c#, certificate

I need to send data to a webservice everyday so I made a scheduled task that runs my code. The problem is the webservice requires a certificate with a PIN code. I have attached the certificate but I can't find a way to set the PIN to it, therefor it shows a popup everytime to enter it manually.

Here is my code for the certificate:

```
private void SendData(string data)
    {
        using (SerWSService webService = new SerWSService())
        {
            string certificateSN = "serial number for the certificate";
            webService.ClientCertificates.Add(FindCertificate(certificateSN));

            webService.SendData(data);
        }
    }

private X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string certserial)
    {
        X509Certificate2 WPE_UserCert = null;
        X509Store wstore = default(X509Store);
        wstore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        wstore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var wcerts = wstore.Certificates;
        foreach (var wcert in wcerts)
        {
            if (wcert.SerialNumber.ToUpper() == certserial.Replace(" ", "").ToUpper())
            {
                WPE_UserCert = wcert;
                break;
            }
        }
        wstore.Close();

        if (WPE_UserCert != null)
        {
            //TO DO: add PIN code to certificate

        }

        return WPE_UserCert;
    }
```

Is there any way I can set the PIN to the certificate?

Answer (score 4):

No, because certificates don't have PINs; (private) keys do.

If you are finding a certificate with a private key and you pass that certificate to a class that expects the unified pair (e.g. SslStream, HttpClient) then there's no real/good solution.

If you are using the private key yourself, you have some leeway:

```
using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    RSACng rsaCng = rsa as RSACng;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = rsa as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

    if (rsaCng != null)
    {
        // Set the PIN, an explicit null terminator is required to this Unicode/UCS-2 string.

        byte[] propertyBytes;

        if (pin[pin.Length - 1] == '\0')
        {
            propertyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin);
        }
        else
        {
            propertyBytes = new byte[Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(pin) + 2];
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin, 0, pin.Length, propertyBytes, 0);
        }

        const string NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY = "SmartCardPin";

        CngProperty pinProperty = new CngProperty(
            NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY,
            propertyBytes,
            CngPropertyOptions.None);

        rsaCng.Key.SetProperty(pinProperty);
    }
    else if (rsaCsp != null)
    {
        // This is possible, but painful.
        // Copy out the CspKeyContainerInfo data into a new CspParameters,
        // build the KeyPassword value on CspParameters,
        // Dispose() the existing instance,
        // and open a new one to replace it.
        //
        // But if you really called GetRSAPrivateKey() and it has returned an RSACng for
        // your device once, it pretty much will forever (until the next
        // new RSA type for Windows is invented... at which point it still
        // won't return an RSACryptoServiceProvider).
    }
    else
    {
        // No other built-in RSA types support setting a PIN programmatically.
    }

    // Use the key here.
    // If you needed to return it, don't put it in a using :)
}
```

Comment: Jeremy (bartonjs), I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20578212/#comment94082325_38250758) you just that the other day, and now I've found this answer, thanks! But... at [Key Storage Property Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/key-storage-property-identifiers) page, that's the text about `NCRYPT_PIN_PROMPT_PROPERTY`: "*This value is not supported.*", and, as the name says "prompt", I thought that this was to show or not the prompt window asking for the PIN... Is that really the correct property for informing the key PIN?

Comment: I actually thought that `NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY` would be the answer, and after that I was in doubt if `NCRYPT_SECURE_PIN_PROPERTY` was the answer, but had no success. But I did not set the null terminator for the byte array. And I was unsure if I had to create a new instance of `RSACng`, in the same way we have to create a new intance of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, but you already answered it here. I was trying to answer to someone in SO in Portuguese: [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347796/86952).

Comment: @PedroGaspar Nope, NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY is, and RSACng doesn't have a SetProperty method.  Fixed the errors in the answer.

Comment: For what it is worth, this doesn't work at least on Windows 10. It throws a "The parameter is incorrect" error on the setProperty call.

Comment: If I set `NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY` with the incorrect PIN, the code throws an exception, saying PIN is incorrect (`The card cannot be accessed because the wrong PIN was presented.`). If I set it to the correct one, and then try to use `rsa.SignData()` I still get a prompt for the PIN. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Afaik the smart card doesn't require to **always prompt** PIN.

Comment: Turns out for my key `rsaCng.Key.UIPolicy.ProtectionLevel` is set to `CngUIProtectionLevels.ForceHighProtection`. Doc says: *A UI prompt is displayed every time the key is accessed.* which is exactly what happens when I try to use it, despite providing the correct pin. This property is of course read-only, so I believe my issue is caused by the key being configured this way.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a CSP private key use `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` to acquire CryptoProv handle and then use `CryptSetProvParam(h,PP_SIGNATURE_PIN,pin,0)` to set the PIN.