# EnvelopedCms how to properly identify certificate to decrypt and not request a password?

Tags: encryption, certificate, x509certificate, smime

I am decrypting SMIME.P7M attachments in emails. I currently have the following

```
                EnvelopedCms envDate = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(data));
                envDate.Decode(data);
                RecipientInfoCollection recips = envDate.RecipientInfos;
                RecipientInfo recipin = recips[0];
                X509Certificate2 x509_2 = LoadCertificate2(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, (SubjectIdentifier)recipin.RecipientIdentifier);
```

And the load certificates looks like this

```
public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate2(StoreLocation storeLocation, SubjectIdentifier identifier)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(storeLocation);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
            X509IssuerSerial issuerSerial;

            if (identifier.Type == SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber)
            {
                issuerSerial = (X509IssuerSerial)identifier.Value;
            }

            foreach (X509Certificate2 c in certCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}Valid Date: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, c.NotBefore);
                if (c.SerialNumber == issuerSerial.SerialNumber && c.Issuer == issuerSerial.IssuerName)
                {
                    x509 = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (x509 == null)
                Console.WriteLine("A x509 certificate for  was not found");
            store.Close();
            return x509;
        }
```

The above code only get the first recipient RecipientInfo recipin = recips[0]; however is the most efficient method to get the appropriate certificate to loop through each recipient and check the store for the SubjectIdentifier?

Once obtaining the correct certificate I use this

```
                X509Certificate2Collection col = new X509Certificate2Collection(x509_2);
                envDate.Decrypt(col);
               decData = envDate.ContentInfo.Content;
```

This prompts for the PIN associated with the privatekey of the certificate, how can I add the PIN prior to calling decrypt so there is no prompt?

Comment: May we assume the private key resides on a pkcs#11 device (smart card, eID, ..)?

Comment: Correct the X509Certificate2 has a private key attached.

Comment: One small correction, the certificate has a private key but it may reside on a smart card or be stored locally.  In any case they will appear in the store and accessing the private key requires a password.

Comment: FYI: If you're searching for matches in the CurrentUser\My store or LocalMachine\My store, that's already done by the `Decrypt` method, in addition to the **extra** certificates provided in the collection.

Comment: Yep got that. But then once the certificate is found and private key is read automatically, then a prompt for password is displayed. I want to find the right certificate give a password for its key expand carry on without the system/ windows prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EnvelopedCms class in .NET Framework doesn't have any way to let you easily programmatically apply a PIN (or other unlocking mechanism); particularly so if the certificate exists in the CurrentUser\My or LocalMachine\My stores (because those are searched prior to any certificates in the extraStore collection).

On .NET Framework 4.7+ you could accomplish it in a very roundabout way for CNG-accessible keys provided that the certificate is not also in the CurrentUser\My or LocalMachine\My stores:

```cs
CngKey key = ExerciseLeftToTheReader();
key.SetProperty(new CngProperty("SmartCardPin", pin, CngPropertyOptions.None));
X509Certificate2 cert = DifferentExerciseLeftToTheReader();

// You need to use tmpCert because this won't do good things if the certificate
// already knows about/how-to-find its associated private key

using (key)
using (X509Certificate2 tmpCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.RawData))
{
   // Need to NOT read the HasPrivateKey property until after the property set.  Debugger beware.
   NativeMethods.CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
       tmpCert.Handle,
       CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID,
       CERT_SET_PROPERTY_INHIBIT_PERSIST_FLAG,
       key.Handle);

   envelopedCms.Decrypt(new X509Certificate2Collection(tmpCert));
}
```

(And, of course, you need to define the P/Invoke for CertSetCertificateContextProperty)

In .NET Core 3.0 this becomes easier (preview 2 is currently available with this feature)... though it does leave you with the burden of determining which RecipientInfo is you, and which key goes with it:

```cs
RecipientInfo recipientInfo = FigureOutWhichOneYouCanMatch();
CngKey key = ExerciseLeftToTheReader();
key.SetProperty(new CngProperty("SmartCardPin", pin, CngPropertyOptions.None));

using (key)
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng(key))
{
    envelopedCms.Decrypt(recipientInfo, rsa);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is something I can test. I’ve found your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626742/how-can-i-set-pin-for-a-x509certificate2-programmatically and this code works for a certificate on a smart card but fails for certificates stored on the PC. Any guesses why?

Comment: @darbid Presumably the software provider is just not checking for that property (possibly it’s bridging to CAPI and not translating the value to CAPI-ese). CAPI keys with pre-set-PINs can be used successfully via the .NET Core approach, but not setting the property on the certificate data.

Comment: Ok so the .Net Framework approach works on certificates on a Smart Card but for Certificates in CurrentUser/Personal I get an "incorrect password" exception when I call setProperty. For these certificates the "Enable strong private key protection" check box is checked. I think this means for Certificates stored in Current/Personal there is NO WAY to add a password we are stuck with an ugly grey 90's dialog.